# How to use Bs4 to scrape content that contains HTML entities

Tags: python, json, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests

*disclaimer: I'm pretty new to python so i might not be able to properly state my doubts*
I am trying to use Bs4 in python to scrape a certain part of a Request response, which I believe is in json format as shown.
[Response Headers](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gsiNd.png). However, when I print the content of the response, it simply prints in a  single long line as shown [response content](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QtO8d.png) and contains entities such as *&quot*; and \n, which makes its impossible for me to try to find the specific part that I need. How do I make it such that the \n actually performs line breaks and the *&quot*; entities are all converted into actually quotations so that I can properly use Bs4 to scrape the content? Is there any other scraper in Python I should be using?

Sorry if my question isnt clear enough, do let me know how I can make my doubts clearer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The data you're trying to print looks like json data. You can try using the [`requests`](https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/master/) module which has a built-in `json` method. Here is an example:

```
# request the endpoint
>>> res = requests.get('https://httpbin.org/get')
# <Response [200]>      '200' means a successful response

# use the json method so we can easily access the data
>>> data=res.json()     

# grab one of the values it contains using json/dict access notation
>>> data['origin']
u'99.54.....'
```

Also, `bs4` is great to scrape **html** content from a site (like if you were to access this page right here and pull all the data from this page). But for data that is already formatted in json, you don't need to use `bs4`, and can use something like `requests` above. It is **MUCH** easier to parse json data than `html/xml` data, so if the data is already in that format you're lucky. You can also parse with `bs4` but it's not necessary:

```
import json
data=json.loads(str(soup))
```

Comment: So I used the json method. However, all the data is stored within one single dictionary header, which is my case is data['content']. Within that content dictionary it lies all the other lines of content. However, theyre in a string format right now. How do i go about accessing each of the different headers within that dictionary now? I tried to do json.load(), but it gave me the error  "json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 7 column 2 (char 14)"

Comment: @lilexperimenter oh, probably the data itself is html. You'd need to parse that into the `bs4` method to parse the html.

Comment: ah FINALLY! That worked so well. Thank you so much for your help! I need to read up way more on the requests module... this seems like such a simple issue that I should have known. Pretty demoralizing to not being able to figure this out myself :/

Comment: @lilexperimenter cool if that's what you need then you can accept the answer. Or if not, let me know what else is needed and I'll try and help!